# HashMap Odd Behavior in Android

Tags: java, android

I have created a HashMap for an Android application and add objects as needed with the addVaue() function below.  When adding a new value the Hash table containing 3 prior additions the table in memory changes which end up dropping the most recently inserted value (name in the sample). I have included the debugger images showing the table for "objectAttributes".

```
private Map<String, Object> objectAttributes=new HashMap<String, Object>();

public void addValue(String key, String value) throws InvalidMessageExcption
{
  if(hasAttribute(key)) {
    try {
      JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(value);
      objectAttributes.put(key, jArray);
    }
    catch(JSONException je) {
      objectAttributes.put(key, value);
    }
  }
  else
    throw new InvalidMessageExcption();
  }
```

### Debugger Hash Table Before Add:

```
[0] id - "123"  
[1] address - "10 Anystreet St"  
[2] null  
[3] name - "Test Name"
```

### Debugger Hash Table After Add:

```
[0] id - "123"  
[1] null  
[2] null  
[3] null  
[4] null  
[5] address - "10 Anystreet St"  
[6] null  
[7] contacts - [JSONArray]
```

The only code called between the debugger views was the **objectAttributes.put(key, jArray);** line.  The extension of the table triggered by the add drops the last value; the extension logic seems flawed.

Has anyone experienced this and/or have a suggestion on what is occurring and how to avoid?

Comment: where calling `addValue` method?

Comment: Maybe try setting the capacity? Weird bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that the remove() method for the HashMap is being called somewhere.

Perhaps place a debug stop point in the remove() method to check if this is indeed what is occurring?

EDIT: Additionally, are you sure you are looking at the same instance of the class containing objectAttributes ? Perhaps there are multiple instances of the containing class?

Comment: The debugger must have been sourcing another object instance.  A reset of the environment cleared the debugger issue and I was able to see that the key values were incorrect.  Weird.  Anyway problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line of `Log.d(TAG, "value=" + value);` in the beginning of 'addValue' to see if you pass null value to `addValue`.